# Error when sending mail in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

i have desktop application and i face this error when sending mail  javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;    nested exception is:  java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

```
~code~

 String host="smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
Properties props = new Properties();

props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host",host);   
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.put("mail.stmp.user", "abc@yahoo.ca");//User name
//To use TLS
 props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
 props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
  props.put("mail.smtp.password", "mypassword"); //Password 
     props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
 Session session1 = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
@Override
protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    String username = "abc@yahoo.ca";
    String password = "mypassword";
   return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
 }
});



 MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session1);
String from = "abc@yahoo.ca";
String subject = "Testing...";

 msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
msg.setRecipient(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
msg.setSubject(subject);
Transport.send(msg);
```

Comment: Eh, your code says `smtp.mail.yahoo.com` but the exception is about `smtp.gmail.com`? WTF?

Comment: where did you set the port?

Answer (score 1):

[YahooMail smtp port](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/pop-server-settings-sln4724.html) is `465` or `587`

Add this :-

`props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");`

or

`props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");`

Answer (score 0):

Did you find the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html)?

These entries will help:

- [How do I access Gmail with JavaMail?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail)
- [How do I debug problems connecting to my mail server?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug)
- [What are some of the most common mistakes people make when using JavaMail?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SendEmail
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {    
      // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
      String to = "abcd@gmail.com";

      // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
      String from = "web@gmail.com";

      // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
      String host = "localhost";

      // Get system properties
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();

      // Setup mail server
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

      // Get the default Session object.
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      try{
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                  new InternetAddress(to));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText("This is actual message");

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```